# Can I override/replace a property of a child-item in a default style

Tags: wpf, styles

The default wpf **MenuItem** (on Menu) is constructed out of controls approx. like this:
grid; outer-rectangle; bg-rectangle; inner-rectangle; **dockpanel**; popup.

The **dockpanel** in turn consists of:
contentpresenter[icon]; path; **contentpresenter[text]**

The **contentpresenter[text]** consists of a `TextBlock` control.

What I want to achieve is to define a `Style`, as simple as possible, to change the `VerticalAlignment` property of this `TextBlock`, but only for the `TextBlock` in `MenuItem`, not in general.

```
<Style x:Key ="TextBlockCenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="TextBlockCenterStyle" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
      </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I tried `Style.Resources` and `ItemContainerStyle`.
Cannot get it to work. `ItemContainerStyle` throws `TargetInvocationException` (from `NullReferenceException`) at run-time.
When it is possible it should be a general solution, something like FindChildControl?!

Comment: is it a item on contextmenu or menu?

Comment: @Gerard, did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ItemContainerStyle?

Something like:

```
 <MenuItem ItemContainerStyle = {StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}../>
```

Then the MyItemContainerStyle have your

```
 <Style x:Key ="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
```

=============== answer after EDIT ======================
try this:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource TextBlockCenterStyle}" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
      </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```